# Make PhotoImage transparent with themes

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-photoimage

```py
        tk.Label(self.info_frame, text = 'Paths:', font = 'bold').grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.info_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'info.png')
        self.info_button = ttk.Button(self.info_frame, image = self.info_icon, command = lambda: messagebox.showinfo('messagebox', '''info'''))
        self.info_button.image = self.info_icon
        self.info_button.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
```

Code works well when when there is no theme [image]. But it is not as I expect when applied `ttkbootstrap` theme [image]

I did not find anything about this issue. Any way to fix? (Image is transparent)

Comment: The image is actually transparent, but the `ttk.Button` has a background color which may be changed if different theme is used.  Note that the label is `tk.Label` which is not affected by changing theme.